# Is pizza sauce vegetarian

Tags: vegetarian

I’m going vegetarian for lent and want to know if I can get pizza we’re going out with my friends, But I’ve heard that sometimes there could be no products in the pizza sauce

Comment: IMO, this is not answerable.  We would have no way of knowing what ingredients a shop may use.  It likely does not include meat, but no certainty as any particular shop may have used meat in their sauce, animal fat, etc.  Does your definition of vegetarian extend toward vegan which would exclude cheese as well?  This is more of a question for an individual shop who would normally be willing and often required to give you an ingredient list for dietary and allergy restricted guests.

Answer (score 1):

Generally pizza sauce is a tomato based sauce that includes tomato, garlic, onion, some herbs and olive oil. No meat included.

Pizza toppings are what will get you into trouble with vegetarian options - many people like meats such as pepperoni, "sausage", or bacon on their pizza. I've also seen a variety of other meats ranging from crocodile to lamb, beef. Cheese is also an animal product, but is considered vegetarian but not vegan.

Long story short: stick to vegetables and cheese toppings with a normal sauce and you will be fine.